# program reversing a sentence in java using character array

Tags: string, reverse

I have to reverse a sentence but the problem is i'm not getting the exact output.
If input is "today is monday" my output is "y a d n o m   s   m o n d a y" 
but I have to get  "y a d n o m  s i  y a d o t"
Please help me out...

```
public class reversesentence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sent = "today is monday";
        char ch[] = sent.toCharArray();
        int n= ch.length;

//        System.out.println("before reverse:");
//        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
//            System.out.print(ch[i]+" ");    
//        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            //System.out.println("hello");
             ch[i]= ch[n-i-1];

        }

        System.out.println("\nafter reverse:");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print(ch[i]+" ");    
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reverse string take a look at apache commons:

```
String reversed = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.reverse(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

decrement n while you increment i (and don't forget `int n = ch.length - 1;`)
also, don't forget to have a different compare - `n >= 0` comes to mind.

[edit]
and note too that you can't do it 'in place', you need a temporary string because once you get to the middle, you're out of characters :) 
[/edit]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a programming exercise for school...

```
public class reversesentence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sent = "today is monday";
        char ch[] = sent.toCharArray();
        char tmp;
        int length = ch.length;
        int maxNdx = length - 1;
        int stopAt = maxNdx / 2;

        for (int ndx = 0; ndx < stopAt; ndx++) {
            int ndx2 = maxNdx - ndx;
            tmp = ch[ndx];
            ch[ndx] = ch[ndx2];
            ch[ndx2] = ch[ndx];
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("After reverse: ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print(ch[i]+" ");    
        }
    }

}
```

In order two swap two items in memory you need a third location to temporarily hold one of them. In this case tmp is the temporary location.

To reverse the array you are swapping the first character for the last character, the 2nd character for the 2nd to last character, etc. Therefore you only need to iterate through 1/2 of the array. The function divides the highest array index in half using integer division, which actually gives you the mathematical floor (for example an array of length 7 has a max index of 6, therefore the middle cell is at index 3).

I kept with your printing of individual characters, but you could use `System.out.println(new String(ch))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> ```
> public class reversesentence {
>  public static void main(String[] args) {
>       String sent = "today is monday";
>       sent = sent.replaceAll(" ", "");
>       char[] s = sent.toCharArray();
>       char ch[] = new char[((sent.length()*2)-1)];
>
>       int j = 0;
>       int i = 0;
>       for(i = sent.length()-1; i>0; i--){
>           ch[j] = s[i];       
>           j++;
>           ch[j] = ' ';
>           j++;
>       }
>       ch[j] = s[i];
>
>       System.out.println(ch);
>   }
> }
> ```

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would state a small correction in above program where in you have stored the value into a temporary variable, but forgot to use it further

```
ch[ndx2] = tmp;
```